# Call Log.p(...) in native iOS code (Codename One)

Tags: codenameone

***This question is relevant only for Codename One native interfaces.***

In Codename One, native code, iOS, I'm trying to do:

```
com_codename1_io_Log_p___java_lang_String(CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_ARG fromNSString(CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_ARG [goCoderLicensingError localizedDescription]));
```

but I get:

```
Implicit declaration of function 'com_codename1_io_Log_p___java_lang_String' is invalid in C99
```

What's wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the header at the top. Specifically:

```c
#include "com_codename1_io_Log.h"
```

C implicitly declares a function it didn't "see" before.