# Call Log.p(…) in native iOS code (Codename One)

Tags: codenameone

I am writing a real time library for Codename one by wrapping the native libraries of Ably. I am invoking native interfaces to include the libraries for each platform, but how can I call Codename one code from the native interface or emit an event? For example, if I subscribe from an iOS client, how can tell the normal Codename One code that a message has been received?

Comment: I suggest you to read the "native code callbacks" section of the developer guide: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_native_code_callbacks

Comment: Also see this question from the other day by @FrancescoGalgani https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476922/call-log-p-in-native-ios-code-codename-one which is also applicable...